# Apache Subversion importing empty trunk, tag and branches sub directory to repo

Tags: svn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux, subversion-edge

I am new to svn. I am trying to import empty subdirectories trunk, tags and branches into my repo. I have already created the directories but going about importing the subs is a problem
I have tried:

## svn import myapp file:///c++/21167222/mysvn/myapp/trunk -m "Initial import"

but I get this error instead

svn: E000002: Can't stat '/c++/21167222/mysvn/myapp/trunk/myapp': No such file or directory

Any solution or better way to go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a directory with all three subdirectories in it. And after that, you add the first one to your repository.

```
mkdir -p init/branches init/tags init/trunk
svn import init/ file://c++/21167222/mysvn/myapp -m "Initial import"
```